# displaying a string on the textview when clicking a button in android

Tags: android

I'm very new to Android development and just started to study.

What I'm trying is to add a button and when that button is pressed a text "my first project" to get displayed in the text view.

With the help of some experts I created the button and text view.

So the button is showing in the simulator but when I click that button nothing happens.

Can anyone please help me with how can I display the text when pressing the button?

.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtView"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <Button
   android:id="@+id/mybtn"
   android:layout_width="50dp"
   android:layout_height="30dp"       />
    <TextView
   android:id="@+id/viewwidth"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"     />
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/viewheight"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"    />

</LinearLayout>
```

.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NameonbuttonclickActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button mybtn;
    TextView txtView;
    String hello;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mybtn= new Button(this);
        txtView=new TextView(this);
        mybtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        printmyname();

        mybtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mybtn);
        txtView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtView);
        txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.viewwidth);
        txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.viewheight);

        hello="This is my first project";

        //setContentView(mybtn);
       // setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public void onClick(View view){
        txtView.setText(hello);         

    //printmyname();
     Toast.makeText(NameonbuttonclickActivity.this, hello, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();               

    }            
    private void printmyname(){
        System.out.println("coming");       

    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
 String hello;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mybtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mybtn);
    txtView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtView);
    txtwidth = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.viewwidth);
    hello="This is my first project";


    mybtn.setOnClickListener(this);
}
public void onClick(View view){
    txtView.setText(hello);
}
```

Check your textview names. Both are same . You must use different object names and you have mentioned that textview object which is not available in your xml layout file.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: i worked thankyou..When i used both text view names same it worked.

Comment: ,can you please tell me what is the function of Toast.makeText(NameonbuttonclickActivity.this, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: Toast() will just create a alert message on the screen for some time depends upon the length you have given in Toast().It requires context,String to display and length of timing of a toast

Comment: @druvisha.ok.if suppose i want to change the title of button how can i do that.can you please help me.

Comment: make a object of your button. Suppose here it is mybtn. You can write mybtn.setText("New Button name"); This line you can write in your java file . and in xml layout file you can add attribute android:text="Button name"

Comment: May your face be successful : U helped a lot

Answer (score 3):

First create xml file as follows. Create one textview and a button:

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/mybutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click Me" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

The first TextView is created by default. You can leave or remove it if you want.
Next one is to create a button
The next one is TextView where you want to display text.

Now coming to the main activity code...
    package com.android.example.simple;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SimpleActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    final Button button1 =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.mybutton);

    //Implement listener for your button so that when you click the 
    //button, android will listen to it.             

     button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {             
        public void onClick(View v) {                 
        // Perform action on click 
            textView.setText("You clicked the button");

        }         });
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot friend.it helped and hope for your help in future also

Answer (score 2):

This is because you **DON'T** associated the OnClickListener() on the button retrieve from the XML layout.

You don't need to create object because they are already created by the Android system when you inflate XML file (with the Activity.setContentLayout( int resourceLayoutId ) method).

Just retrieve them with the findViewById(...) method.

Answer (score 2):

Just check your code in .java class

You had written below line

```
 mybtn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

before initializing the mybtn object I mean

```
mybtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mybtn);
```

just switch this two line or put that line "mybtn.setOnClickListener(this)" after initializing your mybtn object and you will get the answer what you want..

Comment: now always this follows this steps that first initialize all the object and then set the listener or any property to it.. and if my answer is helpfull to you then please accept as an answer..:)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public void onClick(View view){
    txtView.setText("hello");

    //printmyname();
    Toast.makeText(NameonbuttonclickActivity.this, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Also in toast use "Hello"

Answer (score 0):

you use this as `txtView.setText("hello");`

Comment: ,still nothing comes when button is clicked

Comment: add clickable property for button in xml

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mybtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mybtn);
    txtView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtView);

    mybtn .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            txtView.SetText("Your Message");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
hello.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View paramView) {
        text.setText("hello");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**MainActivity.java:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button button1;
    TextView textView1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
         textView1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            textView1.setText("TextView displayed Successfully");

            }
        });

}

}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click here" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```