# Adding a Textview to a Relative Layout in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, textview, android-button

I have a relative layout in my XML file and it contains a button. Now I want that when I press this button, it creates 2 TextViews. Any help please because I am new to Android Studio?  I have tried creating the onClickListener for the button but I am having problems in order to get an object of the current relative layout which I have in the XML.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_brush_your_teeth);

    Intent i = getIntent();

    final Button addAlertButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.AddAlert);

    addAlertButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){



        }
    });
}
```

The following is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.user.dentalapp.BrushYourTeeth"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<!--ALERT 1-->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Alert1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text="Alert 1"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"

    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Time1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text="08:00"
    android:textSize="25dp"

    android:onClick="showTimePickerDialog"

    android:layout_above="@+id/Alert2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"/>

<!--ALERT 2-->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Alert2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text="Alert 2"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"

    android:layout_below="@id/Alert1"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Time2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text="21:00"
    android:textSize="25dp"

    android:layout_below="@id/Alert1"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"

    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"/>


<!--ADD ALERT BUTTON-->
<Button
    android:id="@+id/AddAlert"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text="Add Alert"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:padding="15dp"

    android:layout_below="@id/Alert2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Post your code which you have tried.

Comment: @Masum I posted the code in the question. Thanks

Comment: @SagarNayak I just posted the XML now. Sorry for my late reply

Answer (score 0):

This link may be useful for you:
[displaying a string on the textview when clicking a button in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192109/displaying-a-string-on-the-textview-when-clicking-a-button-in-android)

It is for one string, you may add your second text view into method below:

```
private void printmyname(){
    System.out.println("coming");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_brush_your_teeth);

    final Button addAlertButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AddAlert);

    addAlertButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);

            int prevTextViewId = 0;
            final TextView textView1 = new TextView(this);
            final TextView textView2 = new TextView(this);
            textView1.setText("Text 1");
            textView2.setText("Text 2");

            int curTextViewId = v.getId();

            textView1.setId(curTextViewId+1);
            textView2.setId(curTextViewId+2);

            final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, v.getId()+1);
            textView1.setLayoutParams(params);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, v.getId()+2);
            textView2.setLayoutParams(params);

            layout.addView(textView1, params);
            layout.addView(textView2, params);

        }
    });
}
```

Not sure but something like this helps you

Comment: I copy pasted your code into my project.  However, I am getting an error on the word 'layout' from the 'R.id.layout' and on the 'this' keyword.  By any chance, do you know what am I doing wrong please? Thanks!!