# How to know which button is clicked in android?

Tags: android, button, dynamic, onclick, click

I need to know which dynamically generated button is clicked. My aim is to know clicked button by the user  and use information according to clicked button. I put the code here and I specifically need help for click() method . Could someone help me please?

thanks in advance!

```
public class B3CalibrationExisting extends AppCompatActivity  {

    Button[]  oldButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.b3calibration_existing);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.a0action_bar);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_existingcalibration);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(this);
        layout.addView(scrollView);

        LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this);
        row.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        row.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        scrollView.addView(row);

        SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE_FILE_KEY", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int t = sharedPref.getInt("times",0);

        Set<String> set = sharedPref.getStringSet("calibrationset",null);
        String[] Name = set.toArray(new String[t]);//new String[t]

        String calName = "";
        for(int i=t; i>=0; i--) {

            oldButton[i] = new Button(this);
            oldButton[i].setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            calName = sharedPref.getString("Button_"+i,"");
            oldButton[i].setText(calName);
            oldButton[i].setId(i);
            row.addView(oldButton[i]);

            oldButton[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //your desired functionality
                    click();
                }
            });

        }
    }

    public void click(){

      //I NEED HELP FOR THIS PART 
      // IF I CAN GET ID OF CLICKED BUTTON I WILL BE ABLE TO DO WHAT I WANT 

        int id = oldButton[].getId();

        SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE_FILE_KEY", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putInt("id",id);

        editor.commit();

        Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, A3ExperimentFirst.class);
        startActivity(intent2);
    }
}
```

Comment: please check the answer in (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192109/displaying-a-string-on-the-textview-when-clicking-a-button-in-android), it might help

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick:

```
public void onClick(View v){
  click(v);
}

public void click(View v){
  int id = v.getId();
  // and so on
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to rework a bit your code :

```
final int id=i;
oldButton[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            click(id);
        }
    });
```

Then rework your click function to directly get the ID :

```
public void click(int id){

/* there is no more need for this line since id is passed as parameter
int id = oldButton[].getId();
*/

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE_FILE_KEY", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putInt("id",id);


    editor.commit();


    Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, A3ExperimentFirst.class);
    startActivity(intent2);
```

}

However to be honnest, i think that's a bad way to deal. You'd better directly write your "click()" code on the click listener, and use the "view" passed as argument to identify the button. Instead of a Button sequence, you can use a list, and use get(view) to get the ID.